# Executing Symfony2 specific commands on Ubuntu

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, terminal, symfony-2.1

Earlier I used XAMPP with Symfony2 on Windows 7. There was shell for running specific Symfony2 commands for generating bundles etc. Now I have switched to Ubuntu 13.10. Problem is when I go to Symfony directory and try to execute following command to generate bundles

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

I get following error

```
The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

It says :

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Now how can I run Symfony2 specific commands on Ubuntu?

**Note:** I have installed XAMPP and its running also.

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful while performing below commands

You can delete the lock file with the following command:

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`
You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`
After that, try to install the php5-cli

Comment: still getting this 
`E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
`

Comment: not sure if it will work, but can you reboot your pc and then check? , also were you upgrading anything before ?